# print line in specific order

Tags: python

I want to print around 10 lines in such a way that in every sequence 9 lines print with sign '-'. For example, if x=[1,2,3,4,5]. Now I want to print in following sequence,

```
 1
-2
-3
-4
-5

-1
2
-3
-4
-5

-1
-2
3
-4
-5
..etc.
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This is quite unclear ... What do you mean "9 lines print with sign '-'".  (I'm most confused about the 9 ...)

Comment: These lines are specific for my data analysis software. so as an input i want to print something like,                                                                line1, -line2, -line3, -line4.....-line1,line2,-line3,-line4....-line1,-line2,line3,-line4...-line1,-line2,-line3,line4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use two nested loops, each iterating over the indices.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    for j, xi in enumerate(x):
        if i == j:
            print xi,
        else:
            print -xi,
    print
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [36]: x = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [38]: for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    print map(lambda x:-x,lis[:i]) + [x] + map(lambda x:-x,lis[i+1:])   

[1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
[-1, 2, -3, -4, -5]
[-1, -2, 3, -4, -5]
[-1, -2, -3, 4, -5]
[-1, -2, -3, -4, 5]
```

use `"".join()` to get the expected result from here.